# Fail Java UDF in finish() function

Tags: java, apache-pig

I'm trying to overwrite a UDF's finish() method where I check if the division of two instance variables exceed a certain threshold.

```
public void finish() {
    if (errors / total > threshold) {
        throw new IOException("QA failed").
    }
}
```

My IDE keeps wanting me to surround it with a try/catch block. How do I achieve my original goal of failing within the UDF?

Answer (score 0):

I think an `IllegalStateException` or an `IOError` might be more suitable for your needs as they are unchecked exception and they might resemble your `IOException` more closely than other unchecked exceptions.

Unchecked exceptions, such as `RuntimeException`, `Error` and their subclasses (`IllegalStateException` and `IOError` included), do not require a throws clause and will make your code compile.

If you want you can wrap your`IOException` in one of the above (using the constructor that takes a `Throwable`) and retrieve it later with `Throwable.getCause()`